# Pass mutable array of Int64 from Swift to C

Tags: swift4

I have a simple function in C which fills an array:

```
void process(long long * array, int arraySizeInBytes)
```

trying to call it from Swift passing an array of 5 elements (40 bytes):

```
var a: [Int64]()
a.append(-1)
a.append(-1)
a.append(-1)
a.append(-1)
a.append(-1)
a.withUnsafeBufferPointer { (cArray: UnsafeBufferPointer<Int64>) -> () in
    process(cArray.baseAddress as! UnsafeMutablePointer<Int64>, 5 * Int64.bitWidth/8)
}
```

that leads to EXC_BREAKPOINT crash on the line with `process` call.

Then I tried to just allocate the buffer directly:

```
let a = UnsafeMutablePointer<Int64>.allocate(capacity: 5)
process(a, 5*8)
a.deallocate(capacity: 5)
```

that behaves even stranger - deallocate is never called and I get just a memory leak.

How can I pass an array correctly?

**UPD:**
the second approach has the problem described only when I call the code inside:

```
DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async { .... }
```

when it's on main thread it works, but unfortunately I need to call that in background...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wanted an unsafe mutable buffer pointer, you’d use `withUnsafeMutableBufferPointer` rather than `withUnsafeBufferPointer` with a cast.

But this is all unnecessary. You can just do `process(&a, 5 * 8)`. Swift takes care of the C interoperability for you.

```
var a = [Int64](repeating: -1, count: 5)
process(&a, Int32(a.count * MemoryLayout<Int64>.stride))
```

See [Interacting with C Pointers](https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=6).

Comment: I've tried that, unfortunately doesn't work on background thread (as described in the **UPD**) - the execution in background thread silently ends on `process` call every time. It works in the main thread, but I need that in the background thread... Am I missing something?

Comment: I tested this on a background thread and it worked fine. There must be something else, maybe the lifespan of `a`, that you haven’t included in your question. But I use this pattern with C API (BLAS, vImage, vDSP, etc.) from background threads all the time. Maybe you can create a simple [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that we can use to manifest your problem. It’s hard to diagnose it in the absence of that.

Comment: `a` is a class field in my case and doesn't change during subsequent calls, that's strange if that works for you... I will try to investigate more, thanks for help

Comment: You are right, the problem was at another place - with synchronisation. I've been starting too much threads with `DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async`, so the program crashed before I get any result back from `process` call.